# Placeholder centered but input text left?

Tags: css, placeholder

Would that be possible?

I mean to have a placeholder centered but when I insert a text it will be aligned left???

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: I believe this question has been asked multiple times before (FYI: I haven't downvoted)

Answer (score 3):

[**Codepen link**](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/MYbbzN)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Remember, this will only work for WebKit-based browsers.